# Apache Karaf Bundle Context Listener

Tags: java, spring, osgi, apache-karaf

In web applications we have `ServletContextListener` interface which has method: `contextInitialized` and it is called on application start up. I would like to know is there something similar in the `Apache Karaf` when the `OSGi` bundle is starting that some method would be called by the container and when the bundle is stopping some stop method would be called by the container. Is there something like that in `Apache Karaf`?

I am also using `Spring` in my bundle so maybe somehow this is possible to do using `Spring`? I tried to search for the information how it might be done using `OSGi` and `Apache Karaf` but did not find any information.

Comment: Is this different from the BundleActivator? http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator.html

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed. You can post the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [BundleActivator](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention using Spring you might as well use either Spring-DM or Blueprint. 
With this you don't need a Bundle Activator. If you want to use Spring with Spring-DM you just need to install the spring-dm feature. For Example just type features:install spring-dm in your Karaf console. With that you'll have the Spring-DM installed and it'll pick up all Spring configs placed under META-INF/spring of your bundles. 
The same thing can be achieved by switching to Blueprint. In this case you just need to place your blueprint.xml files under OSGI-INF/blueprint.